# Basic VBA to divide two columns

Tags: vba, for-loop, new-operator, division, basic

I'm new to VBA and new to StackOverflow and just trying to follow tutorials to get the hang of things.
If I have two columns of numbers, column A and B, I want to divide A/B and put the result into C. I want to use a for loop to do so. The code I have so far is:

```
Sub ForLooptoDivide()

Dim i As Integer

 For i = 2 To 6

Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(1, i).Value / Cells(2, i).Value

Next i


End Sub
```

Like I said, I am brand new to this and have just hit a roadblock with tutorials.

Thanks!

Comment: You want *one* loop to do this, not three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention your problem. There many way to do that. Below sub will find last used cell in `Column A` and then iterate to divide `Column A` by `Column B` and put result to `Column C`. Have a try on it...

```
Sub DivideColumns()
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        Cells(i, "C") = Cells(i, "A") / Cells(i, "B")
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know. If you found the answer usefull the consider accepting the answer. Tick mark the answer.

Comment: @Harun24HR Since we don't check whether the cells in column B are filled, it may make sense to add `If Cells (i, "B") <> 0 Then Cells(i, "C") =...`